# Convert system.Type to user defined type

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I am trying to get all the classes inheriting a base class.

```
  public void GetClassNames()
  {

     List<BaseClass> data = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                           .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                           .Where(type => type != null && 
                           type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))).ToList();
  }
```

However, the above code throws an error.
"Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>' to`System.Collections.Generic.List"

How do I cast it to the type BaseClass please?

Comment: A `System.Type` is a type descriptor that contains meta data about a type. It does not contain data about any particular instance of the type that it is describing. A `List<System.Type>` (which is the result of `Assembly.GetType()`) is a list that contains such descriptors, whereas a `List<BaseClass>` is a list that contains concrete instances of `BaseClass` (or a subtype thereof). You should specify what you really want to accomplish, otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting all types of all assemblies that are sub-classes of your `BaseClass`. So you get all types but not instances of those types.

What do you really want? The method name is `GetClassNames`, so maybe you want:

```
public IEnumnerable<string> GetClassNames()
{
    List<string> baseClassNames = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
       .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
       .Where(type => type?.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)) == true)
       .Select(type => type.FullName)
       .ToList();
    return baseClassNames;
}
```

If you instead want all types in all assemblies that derive from your `BaseClass`:

```
public IEnumnerable<Type> GetBaseClassSubTypesInCurrrentAssenblies()
{
    List<Type> baseClassTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
       .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
       .Where(type => type?.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)) == true)
       .ToList();
    return baseClassTypes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my description was a little misleading. I would like to get all the types derived from a base type.